# what is the correct way to bind the hyperlinks path from the model using vuejs

Tags: vue.js

The issue I am having is that I want to bind the map, which is the path and filename to the hyperlink. This seems to work in jsfiddle only. Can someone show me the correct way to add both. I am using map+filename.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   map:'/mypath',
   filename:'/apple.jpg'
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

 <p class="img-caption"><a v-bind:href="map+filename" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Click + </a><br /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do so, but I suggest you use **computed** property:

```
  data: function() {
    return {
      map: "/mypath",
      filename: "/apple.jpg"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filePath: function() {
      return this.map + this.filename;
    }
  },
```

Then your  tag will be like:

```
 <a v-bind:href="filePath" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Click + </a>
```